# iPhone XCode - Copy resources from simulator to device

Tags: iphone, xcode

my goal is to copy all .plist files from the Documents directory on simulator ( I create and store some .plist from my simulator ) and the copy this .plist into my resources files when running on the device!
This because I create a game levels on simulator (using mouse is more simple) and when running on device want automatically load this .plist files into iPhone.

A thing like
`cp /Users/username/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.1/Applications/B5A52177-D17C-4479-AB72-01298392983/Documents/*.plist myResourcesFile on device`

It's the same if I can be able to copy the Document directory from simulator to the device!

Any idea?? I have tried into "Add build phase" and searched into google but don't understand how to do this.

Can someone help me?

Comment: no, I modify the .plist only on the simulator. On the device I must only read the .plist!

Answer (score 1):

If the plist doesn't need to be modified after you copy it from the simulator, you can simply drag and drop it from Finder directly into your Xcode project's resources folder and access it from there.

Comment: no, I don't want do it manually... I can't drag and drop every .plist created on the simulator... I want do it automatically!
(and I don't want to add those .plist to my project don't make sense)

Comment: @BQuadra You can't do it automatically, even if you wrote up a script to seek out and copy the plists from finder, you wouldn't be able to put them on your device in this way. Once Xcode installs your app on your device it is sandboxed and inaccessible.

Comment: If you want to add those Plist files to be added automatically at the runtime then you will have to add some sort of downloading machanism, using which you can download the plist files in your document directory or cache directory and then read from your app. This way you can have dynamic N number of levels which you can create on simulator and then make it available on a web URL, so that app can fetch these new levels at runtime.

Comment: I am sure that can be done coping the files from the simulator document directory and adding it to resources path before the application is copied in the device (using this function CpResource).
You can use the Build phases -> add build phase -> Add run script and write a script that copy the files from the path of simulator and add to the path of the project ( http://runscriptbuildphase.com/ )

But I can't figure out the xcode environment vars that I must use.